# React router navbar header link to other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

index.tsx

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
  },
  {
    path: "about",
    element: <About />,
  },
  {
    path: "speaker",
    element: <Speaker />,
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Header />
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

header.tsx

in header component has link to speaker component

error : Uncaught Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.

erroe: react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Link> component:

```
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Header() {
    return (
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton
                        size="large"
                        edge="start"
                        color="inherit"
                        aria-label="menu"
                        sx={{ mr: 2 }}
                    >
                        <MenuIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                        News
                    </Typography>
                    <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
                    <Link to="/speaker">Speaker</Link>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

Comment: Header have to be inside router provider

Comment: how to header inside provider ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Header` component should be rendered ***within*** a routing context provided by a router. Create a layout route that renders the `Header` component and an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) component for nested routes.

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Outlet />
      </>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      },
      {
        path: "about",
        element: <About />,
      },
      {
        path: "speaker",
        element: <Speaker />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

For more information see [nested routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#nested-routes) in the FAQ.

Comment: Big thanks. Can you explain about <Outlet/>

Comment: @juiz Sure. `Route` components and directly render other `Route` components, i.e. nested routes, and the matched nested route's `element` is rendered into the `Outlet`. I updated my answer to link to some relevant documentation.